# Angular component does not render template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Based on a tutorial from `UI-Router`
 (https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellogalaxy) I have these states in my Angular app:

```
angular
    .module('appRoutes', ["ui.router"])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // An array of state definitions
    var states = [
      { name: 'home', url: '/', component: 'home' },
      { name: 'about', url: '/about', component: 'about' },

    ]

    // Loop over the state definitions and register them
    states.forEach(function(state) {
      console.log(state.component)
      $stateProvider.state(state);
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}]);
```

Here is my other file that contain module declaration:

```
'use strict';

var talentforceApp = angular.module("talentforce", []);

angular
    .module('TalentForce_Application', [
        'appRoutes',
        'talentforce',
        'ngResource'
    ]);
```

And the file for one of those simple components:

```
talentforceApp.component('about', {
  template:  '<h3>About TalentForce</h3>'
})
```

When I run it, my console gives no errors. I checked and the state and component is indeed saved. It just doesn't render. When I click the `About` button of my app, there is no template, just blank and no errors. It is hard to debug since there are no errors. What am I missing here?

Comment: you module are diffrent for componet and template

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('appRoutes').component('about', {
  template:  '<h3>Template</h3>'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely found a solution for this but here it goes anyway.

In the example, all components are part of the same angular module ('hello') whereas you have added to components into a separate module.

You need to add **TalentForce_Application** as a dependency to your main module **appRoutes**.

```
 angular
    .module('appRoutes', ["ui.router", "talentforce"])
    ...
```